# How can I add a second Y axis with plotly Express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

First I will show you the code. I dont have problems gathering data, but more with presenting them the right way.

```
#Get date of comments
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.date


#Get number of comments mentioning each ticker on each day
dfDay = df.groupby(["Ticker","Date"]).sum().reset_index()
dfDay = dfDay[["Ticker", "Date", "Mentions"]]
dfDay["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfDay["Date"])

dfGMEm = dfDay[dfDay["Ticker"]== "GME"]


import yfinance as yf

dfGMEp = yf.download("GME", start="2020-05-01", end="2021-05-15",interval="1d").reset_index()
dfGMEp["CloseAmount"] = dfGMEp["Close"]

dfCombined = pd.concat([dfGMEm, dfGMEp])


import plotly.express as px


fig = px.line(dfCombined, x="Date", y=["Mentions", "Close"], title='GME Erwähnungen',
             color_discrete_sequence=["rgb(229, 81, 39)","rgb(118, 213, 232)" ])



fig.update_layout(title="Erwähnungen - Preis"+"</b><br>Aug 2018 - Mai 2021", titlefont=dict(color='rgb(229, 81, 39)', size=20), plot_bgcolor='rgb(32,36,44)', paper_bgcolor='rgb(32,36,44)')
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="",color='white', showgrid=False, tickfont=dict(size=10))
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Erwähnungen", secondary_y=False, color='white', showgrid=False, titlefont=dict(size=20),gridcolor="rgb(228,49,34)")
fig.update_layout(
    legend=dict(
        title=dict(text="",font=dict(color='white')),
        x=.85, y=1.15,
        font=dict(
            color='white',
            size=15
        )
    )
)
fig.update_traces(line=dict(width=3))
for i in range(0, len(fig.data)):
    fig.data[i].hovertemplate = "<b>%{x}</b><br>$%{y:.0f}<extra></extra>"


fig.show()
```

The Plot created just shows the mentions count on the Y axis. I want to find a way to get a second Y axis representing the Price of the stock.
Does anyone know a way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong here-- but it seems like a bad idea..

2-axis charts are really vulnerable to bias on the programmers part, hard to read for a large amount of people
and the clutter makes it harder for you to distinguish any
trends, patterns
and to take in the theme and story of the chart.

here's an example
http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations

he uses these charts to make crazy correlations that sound ridiculous.
Yes did it on purpose
and there's this blog

---

That provides a lot of nice solutions to think about
they also have this slightly annoying video
explaining their reasons against 2 axes
it holds up
but its long winded. here https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Comment: You are right. After reading the second article I understood the problem of two axis. I guess will stick with one y axis and make a side by side chart! Thank you very much, even if you didnt solved the problem I had you still gave the best answer!